# Side Options Window In ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms, modal-dialog

I have a page like below :

[image]

I would like to :

1. Select an item in the list, say "Popular"
2. A link appears for that selection on the right side. Otherwise its not there or is hidden.
3. I click the link and can select further options from another check list in some sort of box. But it doesnt have to be a box.

What is the **easiest** way of acheiving those items? (assuming I have no javascript experience -- only c# html and some css)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to accomplish this in the front-end (browser), then you will **need** some JavaScript.  HTML and CSS alone won't do it; JavaScript is for handling interactions.  You should probably look into a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/).

Comment: Assume he has no experience in js, I think he is looking for a server-side solution which is possible.

Comment: I did recognize that when reading the question, but thought I might be able to provide some front-end insight - given the CSS tag and the HTML/CSS mentions in the body of the question.

Comment: Thing with javascript is once you start using it, you have to use ajax, and jquery and static page methods and suddenly things get complicated just when all you wanted were some extra options... so are you saying what I want is not possible with my current skill set? I mean if JS is the only option then Ill have to learn it. I just dont want to go overboard.

Comment: I'm saying that the kind of interactively you've described isn't possible with HTML and CSS alone - they're not really programming languages, you know.  There may be ways to get it done in the back-end (C# or ASP.NET) - those are outside of my area of expertise.

Comment: @MuhammadA - Anything is possible, what you've described is simple via server side code (C# / VB.net) for asp.net.  The thing you have to understand is doing something like this in the server side means you have a page where user's may be more irritated (response time is slower because you have to post back to the server).